# What permissions does an ordinary user need in kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to setup elasticsearch/kibana in AWS and we've successfully created enough so we can access it using the 'elasticmaster' role. We can login and input data with this user.

However, we have users who will be creating reports, visualisations etc but we definitely do not want them creating data.
The permission set in kibana seems very odd and unintuitive. Can someone please let me know what permissions this "reporting" user would need. They'll want access to pretty much all the indexes, just read only but they will need permissions to create index patters, visualisations etc.

We're using ES 7.10.

Comment: Are you self-hosting elasticsearch, using AWS elasticsearch, or using something like elasticloud? All of these ways of hosting have differences in how authentication an authorization work.

Comment: Hi, we're using the managed elastic search provided by AWS, EKS,I think it's called.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the built in roles? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-roles.html The `editor` role grants full access to all features in Kibana (including Solutions) and read-only access to data indices.

Comment: @ScaryAardvark EKS is the kubernetes service. Are you using an IAM access policy for AWS elasticsearch?

Comment: @kielni. Yes, sorry, I was mistaken, it's AES/OpenSearch.